# Trying to run simple code that writes a dataframe as a csv file using spark and Java. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my simple code:

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void writeOutput(Dataset<Row> df, String outputPath) {
        df.write()
                .option("header", "true")
                .option("delimiter", "\t")
                .csv(outputPath);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a SparkSession
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("DataFrameWriter")
                .getOrCreate();

        // Create a DataFrame (assuming df is already defined)
        List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create("John", 25, "New York"),
                RowFactory.create("Alice", 30, "San Francisco"),
                RowFactory.create("Bob", 35, "Chicago")
        );

        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("city", DataTypes.StringType, true)
        });

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

        // Specify the output path
        String outputPath = "src/main/java/output";

        // Call the writeOutput method
        writeOutput(df, outputPath);

        // Stop the SparkSession
        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.2.0'


    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And errors:

```
Task :Main.main() FAILED
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.example.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

java -version:

```
java version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)
```

scala -version:

```
Scala code runner version 3.3.0 -- Copyright 2002-2023, LAMP/EPFL
```

Spark: version 3.4.0
Using Scala version 2.12.17 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 17.0.7)

Could you tell me what could be wrong? Pretty simple code, just can't figure out what to check. I've already tried reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `compileOnly` directive for dependencies which implementation will be needed during runtime as stated on Gradle's Java library plugin user guide https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html and blog https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies

Comment: `spark-sql` and `spark-core` should be compileOnly, however... There should be a separate flag for running the gradle task with the compileOnly classpath included... Or, at least some other argument for excluding these packages from build JAR

Comment: Wow, I've been struggling for years, and it turns out it's a problem... Thanks a lot!